# Sybase Jconnect Driver - What is default fetch size and if increasing fetch size can benefit me

Tags: sql, database, query-optimization, sybase

I am using Sybase Jconnect Driver Jconn3 to execute stored procs which return upto a million rows of data. I have learnt from here and there that using a greater fetch size can improve the timing to fetch all the data.

- However I can't figure out that what is the default fetch size for Sybase Jconnect Driver. Can you help with what is default fetch size sybase uses.
- And given that I have sufficient memory/cpu resources to handle
  million resources together, is it advisable to set fetchSize to
  everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch Size sets the number of rows returned in a block from the server.  It's normally set at 0, which means return all rows at one time.  If you have the memory to accept 1,000,000 rows at one time, then you can just leave the setting alone.

If you want to check it, just call getFetchSize() on the statement object.  (You may need to cast the object in to a SybStatement to do this.)

Comment: Is that "*return all rows*" a Sybase thing? Because a fetchSize of 0 does certainly not fetch all rows at once for Oracle.

Comment: Yes.  Fetch size is determined by the vendor.  For Sybase JConnect, a fetch size of 0 says "send it all".

For most of the web systems I design, I set the fetch size to some multiple of the number of rows on the screen.  I find there is no value in receiving data I'm never going to process anyway.

Comment: i don't want to repeat the question so.. here's mine. when i set the fetcSize for Jconnect (Sybase), the app ResultSet returns only one row yet there are million records

Answer (score 1):

After research, I found JDBC driver for Sybase does support streaming. You can setFetchSize() to constrain the amount of data to be kept in memory at one time. If you set the value to 0, it will load the whole set of data into memory.

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0605/html/prjdbc/X11994.htm

Comment: so if use SybCursorResultSet, it supports stream.